# Excel cell with line breaks. tabs with date values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

I didn't found that whats wrong in below code

```
=” Please find a report for  “&TEXT(B4, "dd mmmm, yyyy ")&" | "&TEXT(B4, "dddd");
```

I also want the below lines in single cell.

```
Please find a report for 30 August, 2018 | Thursday
    Total B.T.    =  03 : 10
    Total N.B.T.  =  03 : 20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the quotes are "fancy quotes" that are different for opening and closing quotes. It is likely that you copied the formula from a web site or from a Word or PowerPoint document, which have a nasty habit of converting straight quotes into "fancy" opening and closing quotes.

This formula works fine in my tests:

```
="Please find a report for  "&TEXT(B4, "dd mmmm, yyyy ")&" | "&TEXT(B4, "dddd")
```

[image]

**Edit:** You can insert a line break with `char(10)` and concatenate more text and formulas that look up values, for example:

```
="Please find a report for  "&TEXT(B4, "dd mmmm, yyyy ")&" | "&TEXT(B4, "dddd")
&CHAR(10)&"some more stuff"
&CHAR(10)&"color: "&VLOOKUP(A1,$D$4:$E$10,2,FALSE)
```

Excel cannot use a Tab character in a cell. You will need to add spaces for that.

I used Alt+Enter in the formula to break the formula up into several rows and make it easier to read.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's working, please help me for how to show some values in the next line of the same cell.

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer. If that has helped, please do the right thing and mark the answer.

Comment: Thank You So much. It is a perfect answer.